# How to intercept all Hibernate sessions when they're created (Spring / Grails environment)

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails, aop

Is there a way of intercepting all new Hibernate sessions when they're created? I need to access each Session instance to enable a Hibernate filter with a parameter.

The only solution I've gotten working has involved wrapping the SessionFactory, but this involved a lot of semi nasty hacks as well as it required me to implement around 60 methods, where only a few are interesting.

Hibernate's SessionFactory implementation is for some annoying reason declared final so extending it is not an option. I've also tried aspects and Java proxies without any luck.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "the current solution"? Please provide more details. Also, how does "the current solution" override the sessionFactory bean if its final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem (at least until Hibernate provides a proper API for things like this). Short version of the solution:

1. Proxy the session factory
2. Intercept method invocations to getCurrentSession and use a CurrentSessionContext implementation we've initialized (not Hibernate).

Longer version:
[http://www.developer-b.com/blog/entry/1635/2010/oct/07/intercepting-hibernate-sessions](https://web.archive.org/web/20111124112119/http://www.developer-b.com/blog/entry/1635/2010/oct/07/intercepting-hibernate-sessions)

Sources / Github:
http://github.com/multi-tenant/grails-hibernate-hijacker (still very experimental)

Thanks for the input!

Comment: The Link which you shared is broken: http://www.developer-b.com/blog/entry/1635/2010/oct/07/intercepting-hibernate-sessions . It will be great, if you fix it.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to create a JDK proxy:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionFactoryImplementor;

public class SessionFactoryProxyCreator {

   public static SessionFactory instance;

   public static SessionFactory createProxy(final SessionFactory realSessionFactory) {
      ClassLoader cl = SessionFactory.class.getClassLoader();
      Class<?>[] interfaces = new Class[] { SessionFactory.class, SessionFactoryImplementor.class };
      instance = (SessionFactory)Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl, interfaces, new InvocationHandler() {
         public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

            if ("openSession".equals(method.getName())) {
               System.out.println("NEW SESSION AT " + new Date());
            }

            return method.invoke(realSessionFactory, args);
         }
      });

      return instance;
   }
}
```

and you would call this from a custom SessionFactoryBean:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MyConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean extends ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean {

   public MyConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean() {
      setCurrentSessionContextClass(MyCurrentSessionContext.class);
   }

   @Override
   protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws Exception {
      setExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory(false);
      return SessionFactoryProxyCreator.createProxy(super.buildSessionFactory());
   }

   @Override
   protected SessionFactory newSessionFactory(Configuration config) throws HibernateException {
      setExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory(false);
      return SessionFactoryProxyCreator.createProxy(super.newSessionFactory(config));
   }
}
```

which depends on a modified version of Spring's SpringSessionContext that uses the proxy instead of the real session factory:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.hibernate.context.CurrentSessionContext;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils;

public class MyCurrentSessionContext implements CurrentSessionContext {

   public MyCurrentSessionContext(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {
      // ignore the real sessionFactory, need to use the proxy
   }

   public Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {
      try {
         return (org.hibernate.classic.Session)SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(
               SessionFactoryProxyCreator.instance, false);
      }
      catch (IllegalStateException e) {
         throw new HibernateException(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

This needs to be registered in resources.groovy to replace the standard Grails ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener

beans = {

   sessionFactory(MyConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) {

      def ds = AH.application.config.dataSource
      def hibConfig = AH.application.config.hibernate

      dataSource = ref('dataSource')
      List hibConfigLocations = []
      if (AH.application.classLoader.getResource('hibernate.cfg.xml')) {
         hibConfigLocations << 'classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml'
      }
      def explicitLocations = hibConfig?.config?.location
      if (explicitLocations) {
         if (explicitLocations instanceof Collection) {
            hibConfigLocations.addAll(explicitLocations.collect { it.toString() })
         }
         else {
            hibConfigLocations << hibConfig.config.location.toString()
         }
      }
      configLocations = hibConfigLocations
      if (ds?.configClass) {
         configClass = ds.configClass
      }
      hibernateProperties = ref('hibernateProperties')
      grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication', true)
      lobHandler = ref('lobHandlerDetector')
      entityInterceptor = ref('entityInterceptor')
      eventListeners = ['flush': new PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener(),
                        'pre-load':    ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'post-load':   ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'save':        ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'save-update': ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'post-insert': ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'pre-update':  ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'post-update': ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'pre-delete':  ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor'),
                        'post-delete': ref('eventTriggeringInterceptor')]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the long answer! I was also able to create a proxy for the sessionFactory bean using a post processor and ran into the same "not bound to thread" problem as you did. I never found out what caused it, but since it broke compatibility with other Grails plugins I didn't pursue the issue.

Comment: I figured it out. SessionFactoryImpl creates a SpringSessionContext instance with itself as a constructor parameter, so while the proxy is the thread-local session factory, it can't be found using the real instance as a map key. So I tweaked the code to use a modified SpringSessionContext that ignores the provided instance and uses the proxy.

Comment: This is great stuff, but I think we can make it simpler to remove the session factory proxy, please see my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to follow these steps but I'm newbie to Grails and I'm a bit confused on how to accomplish this. I also tried the post that @BurtBeckwith posted himself about delayed SessionFactory creation (http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=312), which is my ultimate goal, but get confused in the "third connection" part, that is, overriding the sessionFactory bean definition for Grails. Where do I implement these changes? It's in the source code of Grails itself?? Could anyone provide some hints on where and what files should be added/edited? I'm also using Grails 3.2 so probably this is outdated...

Answer (score 2):

Both Burt and Kimble's answers will work, but you can do this more easily. You do need to create a class that implements the Hibernate CurrentSessionContext class, but there is no need to create a proxy for the session factory, as you can override the session creation behaviour in the session context class, then simply specify the name of this class in the properties to your session factory bean. e.g. write your session context like this

```
import org.hibernate.FlushMode;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionFactoryImplementor;

public class MySessionContext extends JTASessionContext {

  public MySessionContext(SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
    super(factory);
  }

  @Override
  protected Session buildOrObtainSession() {
    Session session = super.buildOrObtainSession();
    // do stuff to the session here
    return session;
  }

}
```

Then in the properties you pass to your session factory class, specify this class name:

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.company.MySessionContext
```

For example, in a typical Spring scenario, you might use a Spring factory bean to instantiate your hibernate properties, like this:

```
<bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.company.MySessionContext</prop> 
            // your other Hibernate properties here     
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then typically you'll create a session factory using a Spring session factory bean, such as (note package name will differ for different versions of Hibernate):

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocations" ref="hibernateConfigLocations"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="hibernateEntityInterceptor"/>
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="implicitNamingStrategy" ref="underscoresNamingStrategy"/>
</bean>
```

Hibernate includes three different session context classes, so just override the one relevant to you:

```
org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext
org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext
org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext
```

All three have the method buildOrObtainSession, and the javadoc for the method actually says "provided for subclassing purposes". A JTA session context will be required if you are using transactions that span multiple resources, such as multiple databases, or databases and JMS queues, if you are just accessing a single resource in each transaction, a ThreadLocalSessionContext would be sufficient.

Comment: Could you ellaborate a bit more, please? Any fiddle/github with the proper implementation so we can test it? I'm new to Grails, help about this is very spare on the internet, every tutorial referenced here and there are obsolete or for rather old versions of Grails and I'm unable to get them work. Specially the part about "then in properties" and "override the one relevant to you" are the most tricky to me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look at the [Hibernate-filter plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) - this may be what you want to use or you can at least see how that plugin does it.

Also I believe that the [Multi-tenant plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant) may have some code that uses Hibernate Session filters.

Comment: +1 the hibernate filter plugin is great, we use it to "soft delete" domain objects and it's seamless, check out this post for an example: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/07/13/grails-hibernate-filter-plugin-a-life-saver/

Comment: The Hibernate-filter plugin only enables filters per http request, and only for the current session. As far as I can tell any new sessions created during the request will not be configured with the default filters. 

I'm actually trying to replace the multi-tenant plugin. It (falcone-util) wraps each HibernateSeession and Session in order to rewrite criterias and queries. Using Hibernate filters I hope to avoid wrapping these Hibernate classes and the mess involved with doing so.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably cleanest to have only one place in code where you request a new session from hibernate (for instance in an abstract base class of your DAOs), and enable your filter there.

Comment: That would indeed be the best solution, but Spring / Grails is responsible for this.

Comment: Indeed this is the best solution. Do we need to use a custom Session implementation for this? Do you have any example code for this?